# Inserting a hard-coded UUID via CQLsh (Cassandra)

Tags: cassandra, uuid, cql, cqlsh

Would like to populate some static test data via a CQLsh script.

This doesn't work:  (device_id is UUID)

```
insert into devices (device_id, geohash,name, external_identifier, measures, tags) 
values ('c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a','9q9p3yyrn1', 'Acme1', '936', {'aparPower','actPower','actEnergy'},{'make':'Acme'});
```

> Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant
>   (c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a) for device_id of type uuid

I can't seem to find any CQL function to convert to proper type.  Do I need to do this from a python script?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You should accept the answer as it definitely solves your issue (thinking about the thank you note)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You shouldn't put the quotes around the UUID to stop it being interpreted as a string i.e.

```
insert into devices (device_id, geohash,name, external_identifier, measures, tags) 
 values 
(c37d661d-7e61-49ea-96a5-68c34e83db3a,'9q9p3yyrn1', 'Acme1', '936', {'aparPower','actPower','actEnergy'},{'make':'Acme'});
```

Comment: is there possibility to insert output of uuid() of function into a text field? e.g. insert into devices(....) values ( cast (uuid() as text), '9q9p3yyrn1', ...)

Answer (score -1):

Alternate: Use `uuid()` function. I have tested this in DevCenter 1.6.0.

```
insert into CHANGE_LOG (someid, modifieddatetime, snum, gnum, source) 
values ( uuid() , '2000-12-12 08:00:00', '21A', '', 'system');
```

Comment: This is a poor answer because `uuid()` is not a constant as the OP asked for