# How to update timeuuid column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, timeuuid

How can I update a `timeuuid` column in Cassandra?

I tried the following query

```
cqlsh:mydb> UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = '99b47d70-b465-11e9-8080-808080808080' WHERE mycolumn= '99a53b30-b465-11e9-8080-808080808080';
```

and it failed with message

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (99b47d70-b465-11e9-8080-808080808080) for "mycolumn" of type timeuuid"

So I tried casting the constant values to timeuuid

```
cqlsh:mydb> UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = cast('99b47d70-b465-11e9-8080-808080808080' as timeuuid) WHERE mycolumn= cast('99a53b30-b465-11e9-8080-808080808080' as timeuuid);
```

This time it failed with error

> SyntaxException: line 1:34 no viable alternative at input '(' (UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = cast

I saw the documentation on the cast function, and `timeuuid` is not listed under the output type for any other type.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refCqlFunction.html#refCqlFunction__cast

Does that mean a timeuuid column cannot be updated once created?

**Update:**
I came across the following information on the above page

> UPDATE statements SET clause cannot be used to change PRIMARY KEY fields; therefore a new timeuuid can only be set if the target field is not part of the PRIMARY KEY field.

So, it is possible to update timeuuid columns. `mycolumn` is not part of the PRIMARY key.

**Update 2:**

Even the following command is failing with the same error `no viable alternative at input`

```
UPDATE website SET api_key = api_key WHERE 1;
```

So what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at [Inserting a hard-coded UUID via CQLsh (Cassandra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055630/inserting-a-hard-coded-uuid-via-cqlsh-cassandra)

> You shouldn't put the quotes around the UUID to stop it being interpreted as a string i.e.

There was no need to quote the uuid